# How to dynamically address widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm currently working on a project where you dynamically build the layout. The layout is defined in a JSON file. I have now managed to build up the layout dynamically.

But now I am faced with the question of how I can dynamically address these widgets. The associated data is sent in a second JSON file.

The JSON for the layout looks like this:

```
"page": {
      "pagename": "maingetdatapage",
      "actionputbarcode": "OrderId=233:StaffId=32",
      "row": [
        {
          "name": "line1",
          "edgefloat": "top",
          "column": [
            {
              "name": "maintopleft",
              "widget": "orderinfo",
              "edgefloat": "all",
            },
            {
              "name": "maintopright",
              "widget": "staffwithPicture",
              "edgefloat": "right"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "line2",
          "edgefloat": "all",
          "column": [
            {
              "name": "mainleft",
              "widget": "orderhistory",
              "edgefloat": "left",
            },
            {
              "name": "maindata",
              "widget": "MainDataList",
              "edgefloat": "all",
            },
            {
              "name": "mainright",
              "widget": "MainOccupation",
              "edgefloat": "right"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "line3",
          "edgefloat": "botton",
          "column": [
            {"name": "bottominfo", "widget": "BottomInfo", "edgefloat": "all"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Each element has a name and a widget property.

The name should serve to address the widget so that the data can be inserted at a later point in time.

The data sent in a second step look something like this:

```
 "datas": {
    "field": [
      {
        "area": "maintop",
        "name": "maintop",
        "text": "52236"
      },
      {
        "area": "maintop",
        "name": "maintopright",
        "text": "Meier Anlagenbau"
      },
      {
        "area": "maintop",
        "name": "ordersubject",
        "text": "Kühlzelle sun"
      },
      {
        "area": "maindata",
        "name": "workstepbuttonlist",
        "record": [
          {
            "object": "workstepbutton",
            "layoutversion": "inactive",
            "workstepname": "Maschine rüsten",
            "description": "Laserschnitt"
          },
          {
            "workstepname": "schneiden",
            "description": "Laserschnitt",
            "putcommand": "SetWorkStep:OrderId=566:WorkStepId=44:StaffId=16"
          },
          {
            "object": "workstepbutton",
            "layoutversion": "orderclose",
            "workstepname": "Auftrag beenden",
            "putcommand": "OrderFinish:OrderId=566:StaffId=16"
          },
          {
            "object": "workstepbutton",
            "layoutversion": "workfinish",
            "workstepname": "Geht",
            "putcommand": "BookingFinish:OrderId=566:StaffId=16"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Does anyone have any idea how you can dynamically address a widget so that you can then insert the widget's data in a second step?

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: The json structure is always the same ?

Comment: Yes - there is always an array of rows or columns which contains the final widget.

Comment: What exactly do you man by addressing?

Comment: By addressing I mean how I can find the respective widget again in order to pass the data. My consideration was that the data can be transferred via the respective widget object. So e.g. widgetName.data = exampleData. However, I don't know whether this is the way to do it in practice or whether there is another way of accessing a widget in order to transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Provider` architecture (see [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for an introduction) to save the data in a central place, and each widget can then look it up from there?

Let me give a very brief example:

A widget is built with an identifier `MyWidget(String widgetID)` when the first JSON comes in.

The widget can read from your Provider: `String textToDisplay = context.watch<MyDataProvider>().getContentByID(widgetID)`. Note that the result of this query might initially be empty, or a placeholder String or something. After the second JSON is loaded and correctly saved to `MyDataProvider`, the widget will display the correct content.

Does that make sense?